Plotting mcpfit object with reduced x scale
I have a dataset of 464 observations of 2 variables ("mdata"). The x variable is a time interval and the y variable is a measurement at each time interval. I am using mcp to look for a changepoint sometime between intervals 0 and 3000, which it has identified around "1500." In this case. So far so good.
What I would like to do is plot this changepoint in a way that shows the area of interest only (e.g., the range from 0 to 5000) but I can't get the plot to stop showing the whole 0-15000 range of the x scale.


mdata:
| Level    | Interval |
| -------- | -------- |
| .5       | 300      |
| 1.3      | 5000     |

I first tried:
> plot(fit_mcp)+theme_minimal()

Then, I tried to limit the x and y axes using:
> plot(fit_mcp)+theme_minimal()+xlim(0,5000)+ylim(0,10)

The y axis changes to show between 0 and 10, but the x axis remains from 0 to 15000. I suspect there is some  code in mcp plot that is telling ggplot2 to plot the whole x range but I am unable to figure out how to change it.

Use ggplot2::coord_cartesian() to adjust the limits without altering the data being plotted. Data generation for reprex below the plots.
plot(fit)


Zoom in on the changepoint with coord_cartesian:
plot(fit) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 80))


Data generation
Example taken from mcp documentation.
library(mcp) # JAGS installation required to fit model
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
example <- mcp_example('demo')

model <- list(
  response ~ 1,  
  ~ 0 + time,    
  ~ 1 + time     
)

fit <- mcp(model, data = example$data)
#> Compiling model graph
#>    Resolving undeclared variables
#>    Allocating nodes
#> Graph information:
#>    Observed stochastic nodes: 100
#>    Unobserved stochastic nodes: 7
#>    Total graph size: 1732
#> 
#> Initializing model
#> Finished sampling in 5.4 seconds

